# Issue with detecting whether the shift key is pressed and released

Tags: c, x86, osdev, keyboardinterrupt

Im developing a keyboard driver and it works however I'm also
implementing capital letters. Im trying to set a flag for when the shift key
is being pressed or not so the OS will know when to switch to a new scancode.
It can detect if the shift key is being pressed but sadly NOT when the shift
key is released.

Heres my code:

```
    static void keyboard_callback(registers_t *regs) {
        uint8_t scancode = port_byte_in(0x60);
        // return scancode_to_shift[scancode];

    // scancode_to_captial[scancode];

    unsigned char c = 0;
    if (scancode > SC_MAX) return;
    

    // If shift is pressed.    
    if (scancode == 0x2A)
    {
        shift_hold = true;
    print_string("Pressed!");
    } if (scancode == 0xAA) {
    shift_hold = false;
        print_string("Worked!");
    }
    /*
    if (scancode == BACKSPACE) {
        if (backspace(key_buffer) == true) {
            print_backspace();
        }
    } else if (scancode == ENTER) {
        print_string("\n");
        execute_command(key_buffer);
        key_buffer[0] = '\0';
    } else {
    if (shift_hold == true)
    {
        char letter = scancode_to_shift[(int) scancode];
            append(key_buffer, letter);
            char str[2] = {letter, '\0'};
            print_string(str);
    }
    else if (shift_hold == false)
    {
        char letter = scancode_to_char[(int) scancode];
            append(key_buffer, letter);
            char str[2] = {letter, '\0'};
            print_string(str);
    }
    }
    */
    }

`
```

Unless im wrong 0xAA should be the right code for referencing to the right shift key unreleasing.

I tried googling this issue and there is not a lot of information on this sadly..
And other source code for keyboard drivers seem a little too "complex" for me to implement.

Comment: There's more code than this so I will send more if its needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.

Comment: I assume `SC_MAX` is probably 57. `if (scancode > SC_MAX) return;` is throwing away that scancode before it gets to checking if 0xAA. 0xAA > 57. Maybe you meant to check for the SHIFT state before doing `if (scancode > SC_MAX) return;`

Comment: I want this to always check if the user hits shift so they can decide if they want to enter Capital letters or not.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh wait nevermind I think I see what you mean. Sadly this has not solved the issue. I have seen other people use return methods for shift keys in different source code's of the operating systems

Comment: _"0xAA should be the right code"_ - Can't you log what you get to verify? I'd remove `if (scancode > SC_MAX) return;` and replace the `if`s with a `switch`

Comment: Ahh you mean switch(scancode) ? @TedLyngmo

Comment: @audiotore Yes. `switch(scancode) { case SHIFT_DOWN: shift_hold = true; break; case SHIFT_UP: shift_hold = false; break; ...; default: /* deal with letter lookup */ }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo It didn't make a difference.

Comment: No, not if you are using the wrong scancode for shift up. It's cleaner though. You could simplify your letter retrieval too. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/9oeqeeocn)

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to set a flag for when the shift key is being pressed or not so the OS will know when to switch to a new scancode.

There are 2 shift keys. You need 2 flags (maybe `isLeftShiftDown` and `isRightShiftDown`) that are ORed together (like "`isAnyShiftDown = isLeftShiftDown | isRightShiftDown`") to be able to handle sequences like "left shift pressed, right shift pressed, left shift released" properly.

There is also capslock state; which (for letters and not other keys) makes it more like "`isCapital = (isLeftShiftDown | isRightShiftDown) ^ capsLockState`". For other keys (e.g. "1" vs. "!") the capslock is ignored.

Then there's "control" and "alt" (and number lock) - e.g. "control+alt+shift+A" is not considered a printable character even though "shift+A" by itself would be.

> I tried googling this issue and there is not a lot of information on this sadly..

Try https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard#Driver_Model .

> And other source code for keyboard drivers seem a little too "complex" for me to implement.

Unfortunately (like many things) there's a certain amount of required complexity needed to make it work properly.